# Is every module a direct limit of cyclic modules?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, homological-algebra, flatness

I want to show that

> $M$ is $A$-flat is equivalent to $\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(M,A/I)=0$ for every finitely generated ideal $I$.

I want to show $\mathrm{Tor}^A_1(M,N)=0$ for any $A$-module $N$.

Is every module a direct limit of $A/I$ described above? (If this holds, we can pass from 
$\mathrm{Tor}^A_1(M,A/I)=0$ to $\mathrm{Tor}^A_1(M,N)=0$ by taking direct limit.)

Comment: Every module is the union of its cyclic submodules (because each element of a module lies in the cyclic submodule generated by itself), but I don't see why the set of cyclic submodules should actually be directed (the submodule generated by two elements might not be cyclic).

Comment: Also, I don't understand the first sentence. I'm assuming $A$ is a ring, so, flat over what? I'm guessing you mean to say that $M$ is flat over $A$ if and only if $\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(M,A/I)=0$ for all finitely generated ideals $I$?

Comment: Sorry for my silly mistake...

Comment: @KeenanKidwell: I believe your comments can be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(M,A/I)=0$ is equivalent to the following: the canonical homomorphism $I\otimes_AM\to M$ (that is, $a\otimes m\mapsto am$) is injective, and this is Theorem 7.7 from Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*.